# Jersey - Prevent the mapping of a JavaBean based on QueryParam

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Java class called **Round** with the following constructors

```
public Round(){}

public Round(int id, String name, String uri) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.uri = uri;
}   

public Round(int id, String name, String uri, List<Stage> stages) {
    this(id, name, uri);
    this.stages = stages;
}
```

Sometimes I need to get Rounds with stages other times without stages, so I created a **@QueryParam** with two different @GET methods.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Round> getRounds(@QueryParam("withStages") boolean withStages){
    if(withStages){
        return roundService.getRoundsWithStages();
    }else{
        return roundService.getRounds();
    }
}
```

If I need Rounds with stages I call:

```
/rounds?withStages=true
```

And I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First Round",
    "stages": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stage 1",
        "uri": "stage1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stage 2",
        "uri": "stage2"
      }
    ],
    "uri": "firstround"
   }
   //and so on
```

If without stages I call:

```
/rounds?withStages=false
```

I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First Round",
    "stages": [],
    "uri": "firstround"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Round of 16",
    "stages": [],
    "uri": "roundof16"
  }
  //and so on
```

And you can see when I call **?withStages=false** I get empty array of stages, however, I don't want to obtain it at all. What can I do?

Note that, if I set **@XmlTransient** on the getter of the stages in the round class, I won't be able to obtain the stages in the first option **?withStages=true**

I think a possible solution is to create and extend class for round, and add to it stages. But, is there a better solution?

Comment: Are you using Jackson to generate JSON?

Comment: I am using Jersey jax-rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I had,

```
public Round {
    ...
    private List<Stage> stages = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

I corrected it to:

```
public Round {
    ...
    private List<Stage> stages;
    ...
}
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson for Serialization, you can use `@JsonInclude` annotation to specify when do you want to include certain fields. So in your case, you need to hide `stages` when `withStages=false`. This can be accomplished by using `@JsonInclude` as shown below.

```
public class Round{
     @JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)
     List<Stage> stages
}
```

The above rule specifies that stages should be present only if `stages` is not null. With above rule in place, you have to make sure when `withStages=false`, `stages` is set to null and when withStages=true, stages is not null. There are more options in `@JsonInclude` like `Include.NON_EMPTY` which can also be tried.

Comment: I don't know how to use Jersey with jackson, I added **jersey-json** dependency but **@JsonInclude** annotation didn't appear.

Comment: How did you add **jersey-json**  dependency?  If using maven, Json dependency is added as `<dependency<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId<artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId><version>your.jersey.version</version></dependency>`

Comment: Thanks man, I solved it. I had a mistake, check my answer. (If you want you can remove your answer, Jersey is able to omit Nulls by default without using Jackson.